# Get Managers name and ID from Active directory via client side people picker

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, active-directory, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have a working app that uses's a client side people picker to find users...Once i have my user selected i then need to get the selected users Manager and department.

I don't think this is readily available from the user info, is there a way to query the AD via client side?

Comment: Is the Manager property set in User Profiles? If so, you can use REST: `<site url>/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v='domain\\user'` (might have to encode username)

Comment: Does this give you the manager name only? I will need the Manager ID also unless i will need to make another call to get the manager ID using the name...seem like a lot of hard work!

Comment: You can use `getpropertiesfor` instead of `getuserprofilepropertyfor` to list all properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163800(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use **GetUserProfileByName** operation of [SPServices library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) to query user profile properties of user.Since manager property is "Person" field , you will be able to get ID and name of the manager. Below is a code sample for the same:

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
  async: false,
  AccountName: "domain\\loginname",
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      office = getUPValue(xData.responseXML, "Manager");
   }
});

function getUPValue(x, p) {
  var thisValue = $(x).SPFilterNode("PropertyData").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("Name").text() == p;
  }).find("Values").text();
  return thisValue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that...I've had a look at SPServices before and whilst its excellent, i'm not using it in this project.